# Extend Libreoffice calc Formula Without Overwriting Background Color

Tags: worksheet-function, formatting, libreoffice, libreoffice-calc

How to extend formula without overwriting background color in LibreOffice Calc?
This is similar question to [Extend Excel Formula Without Overwriting Background Color
][1] but for LibreOffice.

Answer (score 0):

1. copy cell
2. select whole area (all cells) you want to paste
3. click right mouse button to show dropdown menu -> Paste Special -> Formula

Tested on LibreOffice 6.3.